# Mysql enum with where in Clause

Tags: mysql, select, enums, where-in

i have two tables

```
tweets(id,user_id,lang); 
//lang is enum (en,fr,ar,ch)

user(id,accepted_lang); 
// accepted_lang is varchar and can vary like en,ar OR ar,fa OR en,fa etc
```

I want to select all tweets with accepted languages by user.

```
select * from tweets where lang in (select accepted_lang from user where id=16); 
#return 0 row
```

If i replace `select accepted_lang from user where id=16` with its result `fa,ar` it will return some of rows

```
select * from tweets where lang in ('fa','ar');
#return some of rows
```

So actually my problem is how to convert varchar to enum or table

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? What does "not working" mean here? Do you get an error, or the wrong results, or nothing at all? Please give more detail. Also, you mention `like` in the title, but I don't see any `like` clause in question.

Comment: i guess it will use like clause, but don't know how

Comment: No, it won't use a `LIKE` clause. It *might* use an `IN` clause (depending on exactly what you're trying to do), but not a `LIKE`. `LIKE` makes no sense at all with an enum field.

Comment: your comment is helpful, please recheck query in question.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you haven't mentioned the second table and got user_lang instead of accepted_lang in your query

```
select * from tweets, user where tweet_lang = accepted_lang and user.id=5
```

However you probably want to accept all tweets from a specific user

```
select * from tweets
left join user on tweets.user_id = user.id
where -- your conditions here
```

Comment: please check question again

Comment: i have just modified question, its more clarify now.

Comment: Is **id** a primary (unique) key in the user table? If accepted_lang is an enum, then it can contain only one value; if a string or something else then it may hold multiple values. Please add the table schema to your question

Comment: id is primary, if i replace query select accepted_lang from user where id=16 with its result fa,ar in query select * from tweets where lang in (select accepted_lang from user where id=16); it will work fine.

Comment: accepted_lang can only hold **ONE** of fa, ar as enums only hold single values. That is why you're only getting some results back

Comment: oh, you are right, my mistake, its varchar. let me check my query again

Comment: that's mean, my question should be how to convert a varchar like fa,ar to a table ('fa','ar').

Comment: ..that explains your problem because the values you get back from your varchar probably do not have quotes so your IN statement is broken.

Comment: correct, let me edit my question. but my question now will not get more answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42379/discussion-between-wasim-and-vogomatix)

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be this:

```
SELECT * FROM tweets, user 
     WHERE tweets.tweet_lang = user.accepted_lang 
           AND user.id=5
```

As there is no column named `user_lang` probably this is accepted_lang

Comment: just modified my question, please check now.